# Determine Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nn!}{(n+100)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, factorial, absolute-convergence

I know that $\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}$ can be reduced to $\frac{1}{n+1}$, but i'm not sure about this one.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nn!}{(n+100)!}$$

In my notes, my professor reduced it to a p-series such as $\frac{1}{n^{100}}$, but I'm not able to replicate his method. How would I go about reducing this series to determine its convergence?

Comment: Hint: $n +k \geqslant n, k = 1,2,\ldots, 100$.

Comment: $$(n+100)!\geq n^{100} n!$$

Comment: Excellent hints in the other comments. Alternatively, use that it is an alternating series.

Comment: @Kusma Why does the alternating nature of the summands have anything to do with the convergence?  The series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: I'm still unable to wrap my head around this concept. I know that for $\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}$ we get $\frac{n!}{(n+1)n!}$ which reduces to $\frac{1}{(n+1)}$. From this I reduce $\frac{n!}{(n+100)!}$ to $\frac{1}{(n+100)}$, but here I don't understand how we achieve the desired $\frac{1}{n^{100}}$

Comment: @AJGK $n!/(n+100)! = 1/((n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+100))$, not $1/(n+100)$.

Comment: oh okay, great, thank you.

Comment: @Mark Viola It is a quick way to see that it *converges*. Of course, showing that it converges absolutely is "better", especially if it is not difficult.